# Render a cached page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, view

I have a simple Rails model that consists of merely one field called 'cache':

```
class CreateCache < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :caches do |t|
      t.belongs_to :statistic
      t.string  :cache
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Model itself:

```
class Cache < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :statistic
end
```

The 'cache' field consists of HTML document and I need to find a way to render it in a separate window (without any layout from Rails) when a user clicking on a link in a view.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Well, for disabling the layout you can use `render layout: false` in your controller action. Since you want to render the content you might want to look into `render body: "raw_data"` though. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html for more information

Comment: But if what you are doing is caching the rendered view of some resource there are better ways since saving/retrieving a HTML document to/from the database is pretty slow.  Also there is no need to reinvent the wheel http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `CacheController` you can do something like this:

```
def show
  @cache_object = Cache.find(params[:id])

  render html: @cache_object.cache.html_safe, layout: false
end
```

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: @DayvanCowboy welcome :) Can you accept it is as valid answer, will beuseful to other people also.

Comment: @DayvanCowboy just accept the answer by clicking on the tick below the answer's votes.